# Greasemonkey, replace every occurence of string every second

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

i try to figure out a greasemonkey script that replaces every onmousedown on a site with an ondblclick. And i want it to constantly update, like every 1,5 Seconds, because the page refreshes using AJAX.

This is the script i came up with, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
window.setInterval(document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace('onmousedown','ondblclick');,1500);
```

The page it should work with is internal use only. But a good example would be the google search, where onmousedown is used for the links of the results to swap out the URL before you click it.

I also tried it without the semicolon after the document.body.innerHTML.replace.

I'm really new to JavaScript, but since i'm the only one in the company who can code, this one is stuck with me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, a small "side question"
Do i have to use @exclude, or is it enough to only use @include internal.companysite.tld* so it will only work on this site ?

Answer (score -1):

A direct answer: you need to supply a function to setInterval - and it's best to set a variable so that you can later cancel it with clearInterval() if necessary.

```
function myF(){document.body....;}
var myIntv = setInterval(myF, 1500);
```

You could also do it using an anonymous function in one line as you're trying to do... do that this way:

```
var myIntv = setInterval(function(){document.body....;}, 1500);
```

I wouldn't suggest this as the solution to your problem. What it sounds like you want to do is manipulate the active DOM - not really change the UI. You likely need something like this:

```
var objs = document.getElementsBy__(); // ById/ByName/etc - depends on which ones you want
for (var i in objs){objs[i].ondblclick = objs[i].onmousedown;objs[i].onmousedown = undefined;} // just an example - but this should convey the basic idea
```

Even better, if you can use jQuery, then you'll be able to select the proper nodes more easily and manipulate the event handlers in a more manageable way:

```
$(".class.for.example").each(function(){this.ondblclick = this.onmousedown;this.onmousedown = undefined;}); // just an example - there are multiple ways to set and clear these
```

Comment: best to ask even small separate questions separately

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it once i'm back at work, which will be Monday.

Also thanks for the advice with the separate question !